# Reading Excel files as Spark Dataframe from ADLS storage

Tags: excel, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

We tried reading excel files in the following ways :

- spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.excel")
- spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
- spark.read.format("excel")

Received an error stating:
**Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key**

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdiY1.png)

Note:

1. *The azure credentials were working fine while trying to read csv file from the same ADLS.*
2. *We have installed the required libraries in Databricks cluster : com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.1.2_0.16.5-pre0 & openpyxl*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to acces to your ADLS

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": f"{client_id}",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": f"{client_secret}",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"}
```

```
def mount_adls(container_name2):
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = f"abfss://{container_name2}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/",
      mount_point = f"/mnt/{storage_account_name}/{container_name2}",
      extra_configs = configs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read .xlsx file and then convert that to spark dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

pdf = pandas.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name='sheetname', inferSchema='true')
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

df.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

The main issue is that pandas would not work with huge clusters and we are expecting the input data to be huge. Converting pandas to spark would still read the data as a pandas dataframe first and we're trying to avoid that.

Comment: Is the excel file in the same container and folder with the same permission as the CSV file?

Comment: Yes, the storage account, container name and path location are all the same

Comment: Are you using secrets scopes (key vault) to access to ADLS ? I think you need more configs options to access  to abfss  i will put some code below try it, it should work